# calling js function in Icefaces

Tags: javascript, icefaces

i have a problem.
scenario:
I am developing a quiz game on which i need to display timer using javascript (jquery.timer.js).
I have created a js file (question.js) (containing a method called as startTimer), which calls jquery.timer.js function for the timer and display timer on the screen.

On clicking of answer button I am calling managed bean method for validating user answer 
and if answer is correct I am changing the question on the screen.

My Queries :
1) How can I include the two js files (question.js and jquery.timer.js)
2) How can I call the js function (startTimer) when my form loads, or when question changes on screen.

Note:
I am using facelet and I need to do above in myquiz.xhtml which contains ui:composition tag.

can anyone help me on this scenario.

any help is appreciable

thanks & regards
rajeshwar

Answer (score 3):

> 1) How can I include the two js files (question.js and jquery.timer.js

inside h:head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="question.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.timer.js"/>
```

> How can I call the js function (startTimer) when my form loads

I'm not sure about this one, but you could use JavascriptContext to send javascript to the browser. For example in your bean when you ready the next question

```
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "call your function();");
```

Answer (score 1):

for #1 i would use:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="question.js" target="head"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.timer.js" target="head"/>
```

for #2, (on Load)just add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
window.onLoad(function(){
    yourFunction();
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

otherwise, just add the `JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall` as user FS mentioned